# How to keep the 'start' time 0 when writing a mp4 video to stdout with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video slideshow from images, then pipe that video to the other command:

```
$ ls -1 *.jpg
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg

$ ffmpeg -y -framerate 0.5 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -f mp4 -movflags empty_moov - | ffprobe -
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1iso6mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 4.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj444p(pc), 430x430 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 76 kb/s, 0.50 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

[progress bar seen in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63RPN.png)

How can I make 'start' time 0.000000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add delay_moov

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 0.5 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -f mp4 -movflags empty_moov+delay_moov - | ffprobe -
```

Comment: You are amazing! It's not even in the documentation https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.ffmpeg.org+delay_moov